# google mock: error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const A'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, googlemock

I am getting below compilation error with DGMessage class while doing google mocking even though I overloaded the XYZMessage class with '=' operator:

```
> t\debug\include\gmock\gmock-actions.h(813): error C2679: binary '=':
> no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const A'
> (or there is no acceptable conversion) 3>        with 3>        [ 3>  
> A=XYZMessage 3>        ] 3>c:\program files (x86)\windows
> kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\guiddef.h(27): note: could be
> '_GUID &_GUID::operator =(_GUID &&)' 3>c:\program files (x86)\windows
> kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\guiddef.h(27): note: or      
> '_GUID &_GUID::operator =(const _GUID &)'
> 3>c:\dg\git\sa3rdparty\crossplatform\googletest\out\googletest-release-1.8.0\windows\x86_64\msvc15.0\static_mt\debug\include\gmock\gmock-actions.h(813):
> note: while trying to match the argument list '(GUID, const A)' 3>    
> with 3>        [ 3>            A=XYZMessage 3>        ]
> 3>c:\dg\git\sa3rdparty\crossplatform\googletest\out\googletest-release-1.8.0\windows\x86_64\msvc15.0\static_mt\debug\include\gmock\gmock-actions.h(446):
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
> testing::internal::SetArgumentPointeeAction<4,XYZMessage,false>::Perform<void,std::tuple<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>>(const
> ArgumentTuple &) const' being compiled 3>        with 3>        [ 3>  
> A1=LPCTSTR, 3>            A2=XYZClientInternal *, 3>           
> A3=XYZMessage &, 3>            A4=XYZMessage &, 3>            A5=GUID *,
> 3>            ArgumentTuple=std::tuple<LPCTSTR ,XYZClientInternal
> *,XYZMessage &,XYZMessage &,_GUID *>
```

'=' operatpr overloaded XYZMessage function:

```
XYZMessage& operator=(const XYZMessage& m)  // Binary operator overloading func.
{
           
    m_header = m.m_header;
    m_items =  m.m_items;
            
    m_logger= m.m_logger;
    m_pMessageCrypto = m.m_pMessageCrypto;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the declaration of your overloaded '=' operator?

Comment: Guess: your operator accepts references to non-const. Add a freaking `const`! Also, VTC uncomplete.

Comment: updated overloaded '=' operator

Comment: Where is the code that produces the error?

Comment: We got the reason. Here one of class member variable is reference member.

Comment: Probably not helpful to this question but I found this question while trying to solve my issue which was I counted params wrong didn't start at 0.